Archive encryption in flutter
I have tried to encrypt an archive. However, since this has already been discussed in other stackoverflow posts (which, by the way, did not work or there were problems with the compatibility of devices), I tried to encrypt an archive with flutter encrypt.
This worked quite well until images were added.
There were problems with various algorithms during decryption.
e.g:
FormatException: Could not find End of Central Directory Record (Salsa20)
Bad state: Invalid token (Fernet)
This is my code:
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt_handler;

extension FileExtension on File {
    encrypt_handler.Algorithm _getEncryptionPassword(String password) {
        final key = encrypt_handler.Key.fromUtf8(password);
        final b64key = encrypt_handler.Key.fromUtf8(base64Url.encode(key.bytes).substring(0,32));
    return encrypt_handler.Fernet(b64key);
    }
    Future<bool> turtleEncrypt(String password, File target) async {
    final encrypter = encrypt_handler.Encrypter(_getEncryptionPassword(password));
        final Stream<List<int>> input = openRead();
        final IOSink output = target.openWrite();
        try {
            await for (var chunk in input) {
                final encryptedChunk = encrypter.encryptBytes(chunk);
                output.add(encryptedChunk.bytes);
            }
            await output.close();
            return true;
        } catch (err) {
            printe(err);
            await output.close();
            return false;
        }
    }
    Future<bool> turtleDecrypt(String password, File target) async {
    final encrypter = encrypt_handler.Encrypter(_getEncryptionPassword(password));
        final input = openRead();
        final output = target.openWrite();
        try {
            await for (var chunk in input) {
                final decryptedChunk = encrypter.decryptBytes(
                    encrypt_handler.Encrypted(Uint8List.fromList(chunk)),
                );
                output.add(decryptedChunk);
            }
            await output.close();
            return true;
        } catch (err) {
            printe(err);
            await output.close();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

I think that the encrypter can't handle the image encoding or at least that's what I think.
But is it even possible to find a solution to this problem or is it simply a library problem?
